# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError when trying to resize image

Tags: python, django, image-processing

I am having an issue with trying to resize images. I got it to work somehow on a different project that uses sqlite3 database, but it doesn't work with my latest project that uses mysql instead.

```
class UserImage(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=True)
    myimage = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default-profile-picture.jpg', upload_to=profile_upload)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author.username} image'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img_read = storage.open(self.myimage.name, 'r')
        img = Image.open(img_read)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
            img.save(in_mem_file, format='JPEG')
            img_write = storage.open(self.myimage.name, 'w+')
            img_write.write(in_mem_file.getvalue())
            img_write.close()

        img_read.close()
```

The error states

> "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start
>   byte. You passed in
>   b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H' ()"

[image]

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: I included the error message, as well as an image. Thanks.